# How do I find out practical information (lines, timetables, frequencies, maps, etc) about the SNCB network in the Bruxelles-Capitale region?

Tags: trains, public-transport, brussels

Various Brussels public transport tickets allow access to the SNCB network in the Bruxelles-Capitale region. By looking at the [map](https://www.stib-mivb.be/netplan-plan-reseau.html?l=fr) provided by STIB, there are many SNCB lines and stations covered. How do I find out practical details for this network, such as timetables, frequencies, lines, and so on? I am only interested in the part inside the Bruxelles-Capitale region, since that is covered by the same tickets used with the local public transport. I could not find this information on the [SNCB website](http://www.belgianrail.be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the map page of the STIB that you mention, you just have to click on "Consultez le plan dynamique" to open the dynamic map. Trains are the dash white and blue lines. Stations have a logo with a white train on a blue background.

In practice you don't have to bother about this. Whenever the train is an option, the STIB journey planner will show it and provide the details.

You should also note that at the time being, train plays a minor role for legs within Brussels.

You can also have a look at the network map if the Belgian Railways (SNCB/NMBS):

http://www.belgianrail.be/fr/service-clientele/outils-voyage/carte-reseau.aspx

The SNCB also provides pdf timetables by line:

http://mobility-brochures.b-rail.be/en/timetable-brochures

Have a look at the following lines:
25, 26, 28, 36, 50, 60, 94, 124 and 161

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw the lines. However I'd like to have a "big picture view" of the timetables and frequencies too, not just searching for specific itineraries. In practice I wouldn't have to bother about this, if my sole aim was to get from A to B, and I just used the STIB journey planner. :-) However, I might want to take an SNCB/NMBS train just for the sake of taking one, and I might even decide which sector to go on based on the information I'm looking for.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope that it helps ...